# Why do I spawn without a gun?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

I constantly spawn without a gun in Battlefield 3.

I would like to know: Is this is a glitch, or a problem with my PS3 or Internet connection? Is anyone else getting this, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Do you literally not have a gun, or is it just invisible?

Comment: You cannot "not have a gun". It must be a glitch.

Comment: You didn't purchase the gun DLC? You'll have to have that to have a gun in multiplayer. :)

Comment: @DoozerBlake that can't be right, that sounds like a Modern Warfare thing!

Comment: @JarrodMosen That's not true. They'd just give you really crappy maps and more lag. =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and according to reports they are working it.  I've had it happen on the PC, but apparently the PS3 is especially susceptible to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I also had a very slow internet connection. When my Wifi connection was upgraded, the no gun glitch was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 18 mbps connection to PSN so that's not the case. I had this issue after 1.01 patch came out. I called EA support and they told me to delete game data and reinstall. That didn't work and then they said to return the game for a new one, so I didn't play it till the new patch came out the other day and since I played around 20 hours and it started again tonight on Saturday, December the 3rd. I think it's a server issue. It only happens to me when during hours when playing volume is high, its not your PS3. I have 3 of them and they all do it. It's a glitch they have to fix.